# How to exclude a particular <div> from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a begineer and I'm having trouble in finding a soln to a problem.
I have a website http://prepfocus.in/test. I've used javascript for scroll effect.
Below is the code :

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 80)
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
        $(".navbar-toggle").click() 
});
});
```

The problem is that it's conflicting with the content under "Testimonials" section. Image(internal link) being clicked isn't showing the text associated with it, on the other hand, it is giving a scrolling effect.

The Testimonial section code can be found out here : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-tabs-responsive

How to correct this ?

P.S: I hope my problem description is clear :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest "helping out" your javascript by applying the behavior specifically rather than globally.

Instead of tying your click behavior to all the links on your page

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')
```

try tying it to anchor tags with a common class (in this example, `nav-link`) and assign that class to every link in your nav bar

```
$('a.nav-link[href*=#]:not([href=#])')
```

or at least assign this function to only your `.nav` anchor tags

```
$('.nav a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')
```

This way, all the other links on your page can behave like they normally would while you "hijack" the behavior of your nav links.

Comment: Glad it did! Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) since it worked

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great solution but what you could do is:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]), a[href*=#]:not([href=#daksh]), a[href*=#]:not([href=#anna]), a[href*=#]:not([href=#wafer])')
```

This will exclude the links you want to use for your testimonial section.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions that should be applicable:

#### stopImmediatePropagation

If you reverse order of click handlers (they are called in the same order as they are created), so that `.nav a` one will be called first, and call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in it. It will prevent the second handler from being called.

#### Delegated handlers

You can make use of event bubbling and jQuery's [delegated event handling](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events): set scrolling handler not directly on `<a>` elements, but e.g. on `<body>` element. Than returning `false` from `.nav a` handler will prevent 'scrolling' handler from being called. It would look roughly like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])', function() {
        // handler code
    });
    $('.nav a').on('click', function(){
        $(".navbar-toggle").click()
        return false;  // prevents delegated handler from being called
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you missing a semicolon? Try this:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
  $(".navbar-toggle").click();
});
```

Comment: Most semicolons are optional in JS. It's good form to use them, but the above case won't cause a problem.